# mobile software that inserts and sends text message to database

Tags: mobile, sms, windows-mobile, mobile-application

I'm looking for a mobile software that will send/receive text messages from mobile phone to a database(if not directly I can build a service or something to receive it) so that the program will insert new messages into specific table and polls another table for outgoing messages. I found a program called Ultrasms that does something similar but it runs on a computer paired with the mobile. I would like the software to actually run on the mobile. I don't really have preference about the mobile OS I just want to build it fast.

If you don't know of any software, do you recommend the easiest way to do this? (Windows Mobile, Android, IPhone, BlackBerry?) and using what language/Framework to do this?

Comment: Where will this database be? On the phone or on an external server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Windows Mobile quite easily. The Compact Framework has the [MessageInterceptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.messageinterception.messageinterceptor.aspx) class which allows you to do something (i.e. inserting it in a database) when a message is received.

Just use a web service on the server which the Windows Mobile device can call to store the message data, and use another function to poll the server and return any messages to the device that need to be sent out.

All the code needed for this is C# and standard available in the .NET Compact Framework, so no need for any third-party DLLs or software.

Comment: Thanks tomlog, Will be easy to constantly make another service call to check for queued messages and send them out?

Comment: Yes, if you just use a Timer that periodicly runs the function to call the web service and process any queued messages you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, text messages, as just text messages by the internet and not a sms service, I would definitely go for android or maybe just a web widget.

Why Android? - its so fast to develop on and I mean crazy fast. Sure its lacking features, but if you want messaging, web, get/post data, this is the platform for you.

If you mean sms text messages, things will be a little more complicated I'm afraid. Involves hiring a sms-service provider and getting the sms text messages from them with the sms-provider API and then you can put messages into your database. This will involve some kind of payment to the provider.